# Android Gradle: Cannot not compile

Tags: android

I'm newbie in android gradle.  I have a problem on compilation.  I have 2 separate project's, once is common_lib (Java lib), once is TestApp (Android). The following is both project structure:

common_lib:
Only has 1 simple class named Hello.java

```
public class Hello {
}
```

build.gardle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

I compile common_lib and the compile is success then I copy common_lib.jar to TestApp\libs project

TestApp:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

build.gardle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

My problem is when I compile the TestApp project, I got the following error:

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexRelease'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with
> >     non-zero exit value 1

If I remove the common_lib.jar from libs folder, I can compile the project.  What is the problem?

Comment: There will be more in info in error. check above line of this one.

Comment: Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
Information:Module "app" was fully rebuilt due to project configuration/dependencies changes
Information:6/21/2015 2:26 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 10s 51ms
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: how did you make jar file ? does it have any android library in it? it may be due to multidex problem.

Comment: Just a simple project, no any jar reference, only have 1 class Hello.java.  You can try it.  Just create 1 java project, 1 android project and copy compiled jar to android project then you will got my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line`compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`and try clean build

**OR**

Just remove any library jar files

Comment: I want to use common_lib.jar, if I remove compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs'), I cannot to use it in TestApp project.

Comment: this could also happen cause of duplicate libs

Comment: No duplicate libs exist, Just 2 simple project's, the libs folder is empty until I copy common_lib.jar in the folder

Comment: what is your java version?

Comment: Work now! The problem is if common_lib.jar is 1.7 java version, so the android SDK need change to 1.7 java SDK to build.